# facing error >soa record not at the top of zone < bind server on centos7

Tags: bind, centos7

I am trying to install BIND server on centos7. 
I configured name.config and db.zone myroot-servers.loc .
I check named-check config and is work properly
but when I give command  for named-checkzone following error occurred

**[root@localhost ~]# named-checkconf
[root@localhost ~]# sudo named-checkzone myroot-servers.loc /etc/named/zones/db.myroot-servers.loc
/etc/named/zones/db.myroot-servers.loc:2: SOA record not at top of zone (IN.myroot-servers.loc)
zone myroot-servers.loc/IN: loading from master file /etc/named/zones/db.myroot-servers.loc failed: not at top of zone
zone myroot-servers.loc/IN: not loaded due to errors.**

named.config

```
    acl "trusted" {
        10.128.10.11;    # ns1 - can be set to localhost
        10.128.20.12;    # ns2
        10.128.100.101;  # host1
        10.128.200.102;  # host2
};
options {
                listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.128.10.11; };
        #        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };

        allow-transfer { 10.128.20.12; };      # disable zone transfers by default

        allow-query { trusted; };  # allows queries from "trusted" clients

        };
        include "/etc/named/named.conf.local";
```

db.myroot-server.loc

```
    $TTL 604800
IN      SOA     ns1.myroot-servers.loc. admin.myroot-servers.loc. (
                              3         ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      ns1.myroot-servers.loc.
    IN      NS      ns2.myroot-servers.loc.

; name servers - A records
ns1.myroot-servers.loc.          IN      A       10.128.10.11
ns2.myroot-servers.loc.          IN      A       10.128.20.12

; 10.128.0.0/16 - A records
host1.myroot-servers.loc.        IN      A      10.128.100.101
host2.myroot-servers.loc.        IN      A      10.128.200.102
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `$origin .myroot-servers.loc` at the top of zone record.

Comment: Also try adding "@  IN A 10.128.10.11"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what made a difference for my experiment.
Regarding `dnssec-signzone` I had the wrong domain in the "-o" flag argument for the given zone file so it was saying (in the syslog)...

loading from master file /etc/bind/Zones/db.somedomain.tld.zone.**signed** failed: *not at top of zone*

*[ BIND 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.5-Ubuntu ]*